# GetThreadContext fails after a successful SuspendThread in Windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7, debugging

I'm encountering an odd issue on a sampling profiler in Windows 7 (no such issues AFAICT on previous Windows OSes, be they 32 or 64 bit).

The profiler works by periodically suspending a thread with [`SuspendThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx), then looks at the context with [`GetThreadContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362(v=vs.85).aspx), before invoking [`ResumeThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086(v=vs.85).aspx) to restart the process. All this is done from the context of the thread of a multimedia timer (for accuracy, at about 1kHZ, which on pre-Windows 7 OSes usually incurs a negligible performance penalty).

Under Windows 7, and Windows 7 only, even though the calls to `SuspendThread` (and `ResumeThread`) all succeed, the calls to `GetThreadContext` fail with error:

> **ERROR_NOACCESS**
>   998 (0x3E6)
>   Invalid access to memory location.

with a very high likeliness, though not all the time.

By that I mean that for some profiling runs, everything will work as it does on other OSes (all the `GetThreadContext` calls will succeed), but for other runs, they will almost all fail (save a dozen maybe, out of tens of thousandths). It's happening with the exact same binaries, the same parameters.

I've tried suggestions on vaguely similar looking issues to repeat the `GetThreadContext` call, with no more success. I've also tried doing a `Sleep` between the `SuspendThread` and `GetThreadContext`, then the `GetThreadContext` succeeds more often, though it results in drastic slowdowns.

It suggests however that Windows 7 OS is returning from `SuspendThread` while the thread has probably not been suspended yet - though, if that's the case, I've no idea how or if to properly wait on the suspension, looping in the thread and pounding `GetThreadContext` doesn't do it.

**Edit:** 16 byte aligning the address of the [`CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284.aspx) structure for `GetThreadContext` as suggested by Dan Bartlett seems to be doing the trick!

Comment: Looks very specific. Maybe you should find a checked build of Windows to find the problem? Did you describe this problem in the MSDN developer forums? Or maybe file a bug at MS directly.

Comment: Did you use the THREAD_ALL_ACCESS property when creating the process? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686769(v=vs.85).aspx which states that "The value of the THREAD_ALL_ACCESS flag increased on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista"...

Comment: CONTEXT is declared with "DECLSPEC_ALIGN(16)" in WinNT.h, maybe it's an alignment issue?

Comment: THREAD_ALL_ACCESS isn't it (there isn't any issue in 2008 & Vista btw, only seven).  
However the alignment seems to be doing the trick!!! Thanks Dan, looks like they changed something in the way the context structure is written to in Win7!

Comment: @Dan: You ought to submit that as an answer so you can get points for it. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at the [GetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, it mentions that

> The CONTEXT structure is highly processor specific. Refer to the WinNt.h header file for processor-specific definitions of this structures and any alignment requirements.

And looking at this file, _CONTEXT is declared with

```
typedef struct DECLSPEC_ALIGN(16) _CONTEXT {
...
```

So it's possible it could be an alignment issue.

Comment: Stupid funny fact: you can call GetThreadContext() on Windows 9x with CONTEXT structure unaligned to 16, but since NT you need to align its memory location in order to GetThreadContext work fine.