# GetThreadContext() returns error 18 - There are no more files

Tags: c++, python, winapi, ctypes

GetThreadContext() returns error 18 - There are no more files. I've searched all over the place and cannot find explanation to the error. Could someone clarify this for me?

Big thanks.

Comment: Do you have Kaspersky AV running?

Comment: So, what are you passing to the function?

Comment: Is this anything to do with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696543/getthreadcontext-fails-after-a-successful-suspendthread-in-windows-7. Have you followed the documentation and suspended the thread first and made sure you've got THREAD_GET_CONTEXT and THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION (if necessary) access rights on the thread?

Comment: Showing us your code around this call might help.

Comment: passing thread handle, which is open with THREAD_ALL_ACCESS. and no, i'm not running Kaspersky. I'm running norton.

Comment: First verify that it returned FALSE, you won't get a valid error code from GetLastError() if it returned TRUE.

Comment: The output you've shown here does not match the code. (The code prints `[*]`, but your output is just `[]`.) Also, your code will *always* print an error code after calling `OpenThread`, but the text will suggest it's really about `GetThreadContext`. The return value from `GetLastError` is only valid if the documentation says it's valid; it doesn't say it's valid if the API function succeeded. The OS is allowed to set the error code *speculatively*, so make sure you check the API return value before paying attention to the error code.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't check return value before printing error code. Simple **if handle == False print error** fixed the thing for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rob Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy)and [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) answered my question below. I wanted to just quote Rob and Hans here as an answer:

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)
*First verify that it [GetThreadContext()] returned FALSE, you won't get a valid error code from GetLastError() if it [GetThreadContext()] returned TRUE.*

[Rob Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy)
*The return value from GetLastError is only valid if the documentation says it's valid; it doesn't say it's valid if the API function succeeded. The OS is allowed to set the error code speculatively, so make sure you check the API return value before paying attention to the error code*

Simple **if handle == False print error** fixed it for me.

Thank you all for your input.