# Getting 0x3e6 when calling GetThreadContext for debugged thread

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, cpu-registers, masm32

I'm building a simple debugger for windows. I want to display the registers context of the debuggee after hitting a breakpoint, But when I call `GetThreadContext`, I get :

```
ERROR_NOACCESS

998 (0x3E6)

Invalid access to memory location.
```

I'm using masm32 and ml compiler (under visual-studio 2019)

Here is my relevant code:

```
.data
 context CONTEXT <?>
 pi PROCESS_INFORMATION <?>
 debug_event DEBUG_EVENT <?> 

...

.code
...
invoke CreateProcess,  NULL, addr command.command, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DEBUG_PROCESS, NULL,NULL, addr starti, addr pi


...

mov context.ContextFlags, CONTEXT_ALL

invoke GetThreadContext, pi.hThread, offset context
```

I've tried to:

1. play around with the flags (CONTEXT_ALL , CONTEXT_FULL)
2. Get the hThread arg via the debug_event struct, like this

   ```
    invoke GetThreadContext, debug_event.u.CreateProcessInfo.hThread, addr context
   ```

But I still got the exact same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Omer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696543/getthreadcontext-fails-after-a-successful-suspendthread-in-windows-7

Comment: what is `RtlGetLastNtStatus` returned ? `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` or  `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` ?

Comment: and in any case you need `ALIGN xx` directive before declare structures in global space.and declare it in global (say context) - very bad and 100% wrong choice in case context.

Comment: I got `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT`, Align 16 worked! thanks